# Swiftの配列内を操作する方法

Tags: swift, ios, iphone, swift4, array

現在、coreMLとVisionを使って画像の物体認識を行うアプリを作成中です。

以下のようなコーディングを行い、画像の物体認識した結果をデバッグエリアに出力しています。
その後、配列の0番目をbestに代入します。

```
func handleClassification(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { fatalError() }
    //print("observations = ", observations)
    guard let best = observations.first else { fatalError() }
```

以下は出力結果です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

配列の0番目の要素はsoccerで推測値が0.909137
配列の1番目の要素はbaseballで推測値が0.087247
といった感じで並んでいます。

画像の物体認識した結果後、配列内の要素の順番を変更したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。
(やってみたいことははっきりとしているのですが、解決方法がわかりません)

■やってみたいこと
画像の物体認識した結果後、
もしbaseballの推測値が0.080000以上のときは、baseballを配列の0番目に変更したいです。
baseballの推測値が0.080000より小さいときは、配列の順番を変更しない。

if文で記述すると以下のような感じになると思います。

```
 if baseballの推測値が0.080000以上だったら {
     baseballを配列の0番目に置く。
 } baseballの推測値が0.080000より小さかったら {
     配列の順番は変更しない。
 }
```

独学でSwiftを学んでいるため分からないことが多いのですが、
そもそも上記のような配列内の操作は可能なのでしょうか。

ご教示いただけますでしょうか、宜しくお願いします。

---

---

■追記

配列の要素を入れ替える方法は、[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/46764)の記事を参考に実装したいと思います。

そのため、以下のようなコーディングを目指しています。

```
if baseballの推測値が0.080000以上だったら {
     配列内のbaseballのindex番号を調べる。
     例えば、画像認識の結果、baseballのindex番号が配列の4番目の場合は、
     配列の0番目と4番目を入れ替える。
 } baseballの推測値が0.080000より小さかったら {
     配列の順番を変更しない。
 }
```

現在は、配列内でbaseballの推測値が0.080000以上であるのか
baseballの推測値が0.080000より小さいのかを察知する方法が
分かりません。

お手数をおかけ致しますがご教示頂けますでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

何点かポイントを。

- 配列(あなたの`observations`)を`let`で宣言すると、その中身を後から変更することはできません。`guard let`ほどポピュラーなイディオムではありませんが、Swiftでは`guard var`なんて宣言もできます。
- `baseballの推測値が0.080000以上だったら`なんて条件を少し書き換えて、「信頼度が0.080000以上で識別子が`"baseball"`の要素があれば」と読み替えてみます。Swiftの`Array`には大変汎用性の高い`index(where:)`と言うメソッドがあるので、それを使えば判定と同時にそのindex番号を得ることができます。
- (現在の)Swiftの`Array`には、`swapAt(_:_:)`というメソッドがあるので、特別に要素入れ替え用の`extension`を定義する必要はありません。

以上をコードの形にまとめると、こんな感じになります。

```
guard var observations = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { fatalError() }
//print("observations = ", observations)
//`identifier`が"baseball"で、`confidence`が0.080000以上の要素のindexを取得する
if let baseballIndex = observations.index(where: {$0.identifier == "baseball" && $0.confidence >= 0.080000}) {
    //取得できたならそのindexと0番目を入れ替え
    observations.swapAt(0, baseballIndex)
} else {
    //配列の順番は変更しない。
}
```

Comment: 頂いたコードを参考にコーディングしたところ、異常なく動作致しました。また、解説が非常に分かりやすく勉強になりました。私は調べてみたものの解決方法が分からず数日悩んでいました。回答頂き有難う御座います。

Comment: @jack_three さん、やりたいことがあってネットなどの情報を探すと、なかなかピタリと決まるキーワードがない限り、うまく見つからなかったり、古すぎる情報に当たったりします。配列の操作で悩んでいるなら、例えば[`Array`型のリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)をぼんやりとでも眺めて、いろんなメソッドをどんな時に使うのか、なんて考える時間を持たれると良いかもしれません。自分なんかもたまにのぞいてみて、「あ、こんな便利なメソッドがあるのに使ってなかった」なんて思うことがあります。

Answer (score 0):

使用されている配列がNSArrayの場合はそのままではむつかしいでしょう。
NSMutableArrayに一度入れ替えると、インデックス操作により要素の入れ替えは簡単になります。

Comment: アドバイス頂き有難うございます。色々と調べてみた結果、要素の入れ替えはhttps://teratail.com/questions/46764の記事を参考にしてみようと思っています。現在は、baseballの推測値が0.020000以上であるかを知る方法がわかりません。ご存知でしたらご教示頂けますでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 自分なりに調べた方法で解決するのであれば、その内容を自己回答という形で回答にして解決済みにしてください。質問の内容を変更するのであれば、別の質問として投稿しなおしてください。

Comment: 質問内容の全てを自己解決できていないため、早急に質問の説明文を編集致します。申し訳ありません。